# ESRI Dashboard: Arcade in List (advanced formatting): filter unique values

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade, dashboard

I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask questions about Esri's Dashboard since it's not GIS *per se* - but it's not getting much traction on Esri's community page: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-dashboards-questions/arcade-in-list-advanced-formatting-filter-unique/m-p/1310003#M8124

I would like to filter data in a Dashboard `List` element to display only unique attribute values.

The dataset looks something like this:

| Site | Year | Species | Count | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | 2019 | Sp1 | 124 | 83.27315 | -100.353 |
| S1 | 2018 | Sp2 | 120 | 83.27315 | -100.353 |
| S1 | 2020 | Sp2 | 8 | 83.27315 | -100.353 |
| S1 | 2020 | Sp3 | 1 | 83.27315 | -100.353 |
| S2 | 2018 | Sp1 | 86 | 63.27315 | -100.359 |
| S2 | 2021 | Sp1 | 1 | 63.27308 | -100.359 |
| S3 | 2019 | Sp1 | 26 | 83.234 | -100.675 |
| S3 | 2018 | Sp1 | 25 | 83.234 | -100.675 |
| S3 | 2020 | Sp4 | 40 | 83.234 | -100.675 |
| S4 | 2021 | Sp1 | 50 | 56.001 | -112.675 |

I would like the `List` element to only display unique **Site** values (S1, S2, S3, S4). I need to keep the **Year** and **Species** attributes for `Category Selector` filters (to filter the list based on those selectors, elsewhere in the Dashboard) - so doing the filtering upstream in `Data Expression` won't work.

In `Advance Formatting`, I'm thinking I need to use the `Distinct()` function but I'm not sure if:

1. this type of filtering is allowed at all in `Advanced Formatting`, and
2. how to call the values returned from the `Distinct()` function in `List`>`List options`
   [image]

Esri tutorials about `Advanced Formatting` for `Lists` are usually about visualizing data (not filtering it), and all the answers I can find in this site on filtering unique/duplicate values relate to `Data Expression`.

Comment: I recently did an ArcGIS Experience Builder training course and this exact question came up for that software as well. The instructor didn't have an answer. It's a definite pain point.

Comment: "Good" to know!

Answer (score 0):

correct the return to be

```
return {
attributes: {
 unique: unique
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Correcting the return to your suggestion doesn't fix the issue: I get a list of Site names with as many rows as the original dataset (i.e. not a list of unique names). 
I used:
var uniquename = Distinct($datapoint.Site);
return { attributes: { unique : uniquename }}